# golang server sending byte array to Android

Tags: java, android, go, tcpsocket

I have met some issue with Java socket and golang. I am trying to develop a golang server that sends/receives byte array to an android client. now the android client can send byte array to go server but cannot receive anything from go server. I have attached the code below.

The code got stuck when reach in.read(); I tried `in.available()` to see how many bytes are in the inputstream. it always shows 0:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button regButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.regbut);
    msg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.msg);

    regButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    byte[] array;
                    BigInteger mykey = mykey(publicKey);
                    System.out.println(mykey);
                    BigInteger rawkey = generater.modPow(mykey,publicKey);
                    BigInteger serverRawKey;
                    System.out.println(rawkey);
                    array = rawkey.toByteArray();
                    System.out.println(rawkey.bitCount());
                    try{
                        Socket con = new Socket("149.166.134.55",9999);
                        OutputStream out = con.getOutputStream();
                        InputStream in = con.getInputStream();
                        DataOutputStream dOut = new DataOutputStream(out);
                        //DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(in);
                        byte[] data = new byte[10];
                        dOut.write(array);
                        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
                        System.out.println(in.available());
                        in.read(data);
                        con.close();
                        }catch (Exception e){
                        System.out.println(e);
                       }
                   }
               }).start();
           }
        });
         }
```

here is the go code. if i remove in.read(); in java everything works just fine. but it pauses when I add in.read();

```
var publickey *big.Int

func ClientListen(port string) {
    ln, err := net.Listen("tcp", port)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error\n")
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    for {
        nc, err := ln.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            continue
        }
        go recivemsg(nc)
    }
}

func recivemsg(nc net.Conn) {
    publickey = big.NewInt(15485863)
    var msg []byte
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    rawkey := big.NewInt(0)
    io.Copy(&buf, nc)
    fmt.Println("total size:", buf.Len())
    msg = buf.Bytes()
    rawkey = rawkey.SetBytes(msg)
    fmt.Println(msg, "    ", rawkey)
    r := rand.New(rand.NewSource(99))
    myraw := big.NewInt(0)
    myraw = myraw.Rand(r, publickey)
    fmt.Println(myraw)
    newmsg := myraw.Bytes()
    nc.Write(newmsg)
    nc.Close()
    fmt.Println(nc.RemoteAddr())

}

func main() {
    ClientListen(":9999")
}
```

thanks guys for taking your time to read my question

Comment: Your Go code is relying on the connection closing to signal the end of the message. The sender either needs to close the connection, or you need some other protocol to delimit messages.

Comment: so I need to establish another connection to send to message back to Java?

Comment: No, you just need a protocol for sending messages: fixed length, length prefixed, newline delimited, http, etc. A TCP connection is a stream, it doesn't send individual messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`io.Copy(&buf, nc)` on Go side will continue to read from the connection's input stream until it's closed. On Java side, you try to read from the connection's input stream, but Go side is still waiting for further input, since Java is still keeping its output steam (Go's input stream) open.

Solution: on Java side, close the output stream using the socket's [`shutdownOutput()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#shutdownOutput()) method after you are done writing to it.

Comment: I used socket.shutdownOutput() and it works for me. for anyone who have the similar question don't use outputstream.close(); it will shut the entire socket down.

Comment: Thanks @ZhijieLi for that important detail!